# How to increase the EBS volume of a running ec2 instance using cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ebs

Can we update EBS volume attached to a running ec2 instance using cloudformation?
I know we can do it through console or CLI. Is there a way to do it using cloudformation?

Comment: Did you create this instance using cloudformation or manually?

Comment: This instance was created through cloudformation.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use the [BlockDeviceMapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/block-device-mapping-concepts.html) to adjust the size of your volume, something like this

```
BlockDeviceMappings" : [
   {
      "DeviceName" : "/dev/sda1",
      "Ebs" : { "VolumeSize" : "100" }
   }
]
```

Comment: Ec2 instance is already running. How do we provide the ec2 instanceId for which we need to update the volume?

Comment: EC2 allows updating the disk size even when the instances are running so cloudformation should follow the same behavior

Comment: I would recommend trying this on a 'test stack' before doing it to your real system, in case it results in data loss. Definitely take a Snapshot of the volume beforehand, too.

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is about [Update Behaviors of Stack Resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-updating-stacks-update-behaviors.html), I recommend checking the `UpdateType` field in the [AWS CloudFormation Resource Specification](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-resource-specification.html) and the `Update requires:` snippet in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#cfn-ec2-instance-blockdevicemappings), and checking out these features that help prevent accidental deletion of CloudFormation resources during stack updates:

[`UpdateReplacePolicy`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-updatereplacepolicy.html)

[`Change sets`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-updating-stacks-changesets.html)

[`IAM stack policies`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/protect-stack-resources.html)

Comment: Thanks for pointing to this! When i try to update stack to increase ebs volume, replacement is "true" and a new ec2 instance is created with new volume. CLoudformation tries to terminate old instance. How can this be avoided?  Need to expand the current volume and not create a new one.

Comment: https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/112

Comment: Makes sense.. So I should just go with CLI or console to increase ebs volume.